# Creating a matrix using KQL

Tags: matrix, kql, kusto-explorer

This is a matrix from a job I have in Databricks. I have cropped out the task names (which usually sits on the left side of the matrix. The green dots show when a task ran successful. I want to recreate this using KQL. I have three columns of data. Time generated, ActionName (whether is passed or failed), and table name. I have records for each table for many months but only need a 2 week matrix. Many thanks if anyone can help.

[A example of the matrix mentioned above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SBMI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of

```
// Generation of a data sample. Not part of the solution.
let t = materialize (print table_id = range(1,10), dt = range(startofday(ago(20d)), now(), 1d) | mv-expand table_id | mv-expand dt | extend TimeGenerated = todatetime(dt), TableName = strcat("table_",table_id), ActionName  = dynamic(["Passed","Failed"])[toint(rand(2))] | where rand() < 0.9);
// Solution starts here.
t
| extend TimeGenerated = format_datetime (TimeGenerated, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
| evaluate pivot(TimeGenerated, any(iff(ActionName == "Passed", make_string(129001), make_string(128997))), TableName)
```

| TableName | 2022-04-01 | 2022-04-02 | 2022-04-03 | 2022-04-04 | 2022-04-05 | 2022-04-06 | 2022-04-07 | 2022-04-08 | 2022-04-09 | 2022-04-10 | 2022-04-11 | 2022-04-12 | 2022-04-13 | 2022-04-14 | 2022-04-15 | 2022-04-16 | 2022-04-17 | 2022-04-18 | 2022-04-19 | 2022-04-20 | 2022-04-21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| table_1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| table_2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| table_3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| table_4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| table_5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| table_6 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| table_7 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| table_8 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| table_9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| table_10 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3WRTW/CMAyG7/0VVi8kUukHl63aOOyynUCTxg0h5BEXorVJ1ZqPTvz4uQw2hrRcYr1%209caPkyTwQo4aZOsd%20AIQDDJCi1VdUgxTDzU23Hd4Q9D6cts746AkBoYxVMjUWCztJ4GqG%20tExveSltZIt0G3JpVFWaojMPyjtCyhvjDYKVx7NUqNFoPzeyVXZjQcodoN6VCjM79516KEHYEOTFLPbEVnCupfZS8MxKIqwxI46wOmWJH0Wm5WyCr8Dg2jS7jYnlY92sknRtM5rOxKzcNXbFsyYRQ%20oy2lWOg5ewFVwmLUSOuFjLLfUENwUjQ8Qhrn%20iFIEng7bwxOyC30tjjg4N/hC9/ITpcXAlB/DBEMOjnDyWRozED3MTsst9KC2u4837rRdcoWhbpiG4/hB0m%2074OWshPr1iob5Wma6VvxPs/vtL5eo/4CLep1WTYCAAA=)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect. One question, the 'make_string' part is that referring to the different colours? Thanks again

Comment: It is a way to create Unicode characters, in this case red & green large squares. (1) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/makestringfunction (2) https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F7E5 (3) https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F7E9

Comment: Thank you so much, I have just accepted to answer. Also, if I wanted to create a table where if any of the tables failed on a given day there was just 1 red dot and if they all passed there was a green dot, how would I go about this? thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Please open a new post for this question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72044522/producing-a-single-row-matrix-using-kql this is the new link, thanks